# MsgBox does not pop when given multiple arguments in If / Then statement

Tags: excel, vba

When i select cell C1, if A1 is empty, i want a message box to pop up. Though nothing actually happens (no error message either). Is my syntax wrong or am i going about it the wrong way?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "C1" And Range("A1") Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please fill out previous fields to continue"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$1" And Range("A1").Value = "" Then 'or IsEmpty(Range("A1"))
        MsgBox "Please fill out previous fields to continue"
    End If

End Sub
```

`Target.Address` would return `$C$1` - so that's needed there. And `Is Nothing` isn't used for determining if a cell is empty - that would be `IsEmpty()` or `.Value = ""` - `Is Nothing` is used more for determining if an `Object` has been `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A1")` returns a `Range` object that represents the cell at `A1` - this will never be `Nothing` because `A1` will always exist as a cell.

You can `And IsEmpty(Range("A1"))` to see if it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$1" And Len(Range("A1")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please fill out previous fields to continue"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for You:

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "C1" And IsEmpty(Range("A1")) = True Then
    MsgBox "Please fill out previous fields to continue"
End If
```

End Sub